# How to create a sub folder within an exisiting folder in a document library with power automate

Tags: workflow, power-automate

I am trying to create a sub folder when a new request is added to my jobs list using power automate.  At the root level of the document library, I have a root main folder, example; named Photo-Request-FY24.  When the request comes submitted, I like to add a sub folder within specific main folders the name, Photo-request-0001; the next request submitted will create a new folder named Photo-request-0002; and so on.

Currently I have the flow working but the folders are added to the root level, which adds to the other folders at the root level, adding clutter.  I’m trying to keep my file separate from the other file within the document library.  Below is how I’m trying to develop the folder structure.

(All filed is the same Document library)
Templates
Photo-Request-FY24 (this is a separate list)
Photo-request-0001
Photo-request-0002
Video-Request-FY24 (this is a separate list)
Video-request-0001
Video-request-0002
Graphic-Request-FY24 (this is a separate list0
Graphic-request-0001
Graphic-request-0002
Graphic-request-0002
Newsletters
Factsheets

I thought this would be easy and straight forward to figure out but I’m not able to target the different root folders to create the sub-folders.  I can just add the new folders at the root level of the document library.   Any guidance on how to create the power automate action would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I found out after a few more tries it was straight forward.  To target an existing folder in the document library you write the "File Path" as followed:  File Path: /Existing folder name/Name of new folder.  I didn't add the "/" at the beginning of the path when I attempted this in my earlier tries.

[image]